# Align and distribute layers relative to canvas

Tags: gimp

How can I use GIMP to equally align and distribute multiple images over multiple layers relative to the canvas?

Ideally, the following would be before:

[image]

Ideally, the following would be after:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To center them in the image, use the [Align tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-align.html)

To evenly space layers vertically or horizontally try the [arrange-layers script](http://gimp-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml).

Comment: Regarding the arrange-layers script, I'm getting `Designated span (724px) smaller than larger later size (1000px)`?

Comment: Yes, it says that if a layer is bigger than what you are trying to fit it in... Are you including the background layer, by any chance? The script works on the visible layers so mask the background out...

Comment: Along with using `Layer` | `Autocrop layer`, that worked great, thank you!